# Getting 403 errors for spring boot login with a load balancer

Tags: java, spring-security, oauth-2.0

We have an oauth2 spring boot server that will occasionally return a 403 error when users POST to the login page.  I can see the 403 error on the actual POST to the login endpoint in the HTTP access logs.

At first, we figured it was due to the csrf, but we configured it to use the HTTP Only cookies and are still having the same problem.  I verified that the cookies are being set using the browser debug console.

Any tips on debugging the problem to figure out why it's returning 403 errors?

Here's our spring security configuration.

```
http
        .csrf().csrfTokenRepository(new CookieCsrfTokenRepository())
        .and()
        .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/actuator/health").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/webjars/**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/assets/**").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/login?error*").permitAll()
          .anyRequest().authenticated() // every request requires the user to authenticated
        .and()
        .logout()
          .logoutSuccessUrl("/login?logout")
        .and()
        .formLogin()
          .loginPage("/login")  //when authentication is needed, redirect to /login
          .failureHandler(loginFailureHandler())
          .authenticationDetailsSource(authenticationDetailsSource)
          .permitAll();
```

Comment: Please disable `CSRF` protection because it is enabled by default in spring security. Additionally you need to implement code to allow `CORS` origin.

Comment: CSRF should be ok since I've got it configured using cookies instead of session based. 
For CORS I'm coming from the same domain.